# Error page with “No message available” From Spring Application

Tags: spring-boot

My Main entry class

```
package com.project.cloud;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;

@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloworldClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloworldClientApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Resource file

```
   package com.project.controller;

   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
   import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

   /**
   *
   * @author Wasp Networks
   */
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/rest/client/helloworld")
    public class HelloResources {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @GetMapping
    public String Entry(){
        String url = "http://helloworld-server/rest/server/helloworld";
        return restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String Main(){
       return "Helloworld client!.";
    }

}
```

My Config class

```
package com.project.configuration;
/**
*
* @author Wasp Networks
*/
import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalanced;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;


@Configuration
public class Configure {
    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

if your spring code structure is like this and you try running the application, don't be surprise to get error on the web console.

sorry guy for my bad English....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issues is placing our packages in a nested order, if you have a look at the code the packages are not nested rather placed in the same folder/package "project".

**Instead of This:-**

```
    package com.project.cloud;
    package com.project.controller;
    package com.project.configuration;
```

**Do of This:-**

```
    package com.project.cloud;
    package com.project.cloud.controller;
    package com.project.cloud.configuration;
```

create other packages under the main entry point package of your application where @SpringBootApplication is defined, when using this annotation @SpringBootApplication it scans only the package you place it.......hope this helps.